# Get all elements which have both values grouped by ParentId

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following problem:

I have a relation table like this:

```
ParentId | ValueId
1          1   
1          2
2          3
2          4
2          1
```

Then, I want to get the ParentId who have exactly the values which query say, no more, no less.

I have this query actually:

```
SELECT "ParentId" FROM public."ParentValueRelation"
WHERE "ValueId" = 1 AND "ValueId" = 2
GROUP BY "ParentId"
```

Expected to receive 1 but getting null

Answer in sequelize could be great but not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of ways to do this in Postgres.  Like this for instance:

```
SELECT "ParentId" FROM public."ParentValueRelation"
WHERE "ValueId" = 1 OR "ValueId" = 2
GROUP BY "ParentId"
HAVING COUNT("ValueID")=2
```

If there are duplicates in the table, you need to replace the having clause with

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "ValueID")=2
```

Best regards,Bjarni